# How do I test that my Celery worker actually works in Django

Tags: django, celery

(code at bottom)

**Context**: I'm working on a Django project where I need to provide the user feedback on a task that takes 15-45 seconds. In comes Celery to the rescue! I can see that Celery is performing as expected when I `celery -A my_project worker -l info & python manage.py runserver`.

**Problem**: I can't figure out how to run a celery worker in my tests. When I run `python manage.py test`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/pbrockman/coding/t1v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 387, in inner
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/pbrockman/coding/tcommerce/tcommerce/tests.py", line 58, in test_shared_celery_task
   self.assertEqual(result.get(), 6)
 File "/Users/pbrockman/coding/t1v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 224, in get
   return self.backend.wait_for_pending(
 File "/Users/pbrockman/coding/t1v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 756, in wait_for_pending
   meta = self.wait_for(
 File "/Users/pbrockman/coding/t1v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 1087, in _is_disabled
   raise NotImplementedError(E_NO_BACKEND.strip())
NotImplementedError: No result backend is configured.
Please see the documentation for more information.
```

**Attempted solution**:

- I tried various combinations of @override_settings with `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True`, `CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPOGATES=True`, and `BROKER_BACKEND='memory'`.
- I tried both `@app.task` decorator and the `@shared_task` decorator.

How do I see if celery is having the expected behavior in my tests?

#### Code

**Celery Settings: my_project/celery.py**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv() 
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')

app = Celery('my_project-{os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT")}',
             broker=os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL'),
             include=['my_project.tasks'])

from django.conf import settings
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**Testing: my_project/tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from tcommerce.celery import app
from tcommerce.tasks import shared_add
from tcommerce.tasks import app_add

class CeleryTests(TestCase):

  def test_shared_celery_task(self):
    '@shared_task'
    result = shared_add.delay(2, 4)
    self.assertEqual(result.get(), 6)

  
  def test_app_celery_task(self):
    '@task.app'
    result = app_add.delay(2, 4)
    self.assertEqual(result.get(), 6)
```

**Defining tasks: my_project/tasks.py**

```
from .celery import app
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def shared_add(x, y):
  return x + y

@app.task
def app_add(x, y):
  return x + y
```

Comment: Not sure if you'll still get the exception, but you could try replacing `.delay(2, 4)` with `.apply(2, 4, throw=True)`.  The change makes it call the task immediately without going through the broker and `throw=True` allows exceptions to be raised.

Comment: I think that is one direction to go. 

In the context of this project, I'm using celery to cause django-channels to fire a message on a WebSocket. 

I was having some luck in integration testing using the builtin async_client, but I was curious about specifically testing celery in a unit test

Comment: Also not sure if it helps, but I've run tests using "eager" and never set `BROKER_BACKEND`.  I'm not even sure what that is since all celery settings in Django start with `CELERY_`.  When in "eager" mode, though, no broker is used.  Also, you misspelled "PROPAGATES" (2nd O should be an A).